# Code shorter intersection in VB.Net function

Tags: vb.net

How do I shorten this? I want after each `TxtNumberListScan.Lines (i) .Split ("")` to calculate my values, not all to a whole. That's why I did not manage to shorten my code, could it be make it shorter?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Dim intersectionList As New List(Of String)()
        For i As Integer = 1 To TxtCheckDraws.Text
            Dim firstBoxList = TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(i).Split(",")
            Dim secondBoxList = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(1).Split(" ")
            intersectionList.Add(String.Join(",", secondBoxList.Intersect(firstBoxList)))
        Next
        TxtMReadOnly.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, intersectionList)
        TxtNumberListCount.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtMReadOnly.Text.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).Count()
        While ListBoxRemize1.Items.Count > 0
            ListBoxRemize1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBoxRemize1.Items.Count - 1)
        End While
        For i As Integer = 0 To TxtMReadOnly.Lines.Count - 1
            ListBoxRemize1.Items.Add(TxtMReadOnly.Lines(i))
        Next
        TxtMReadOnly.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Try
        Dim intersectionList As New List(Of String)()
        For i As Integer = 1 To TxtCheckDraws.Text
            Dim firstBoxList = TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(i).Split(",")
            Dim secondBoxList = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(2).Split(" ")
            intersectionList.Add(String.Join(",", secondBoxList.Intersect(firstBoxList)))
        Next
        TxtMReadOnly.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, intersectionList)
        TxtNumberListCount.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtMReadOnly.Text.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).Count()
        While ListBoxRemize2.Items.Count > 0
            ListBoxRemize2.Items.RemoveAt(ListBoxRemize2.Items.Count - 1)
        End While
        For i As Integer = 0 To TxtMReadOnly.Lines.Count - 1
            ListBoxRemize2.Items.Add(TxtMReadOnly.Lines(i))
        Next
        TxtMReadOnly.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Try
        Dim intersectionList As New List(Of String)()
        For i As Integer = 1 To TxtCheckDraws.Text
            Dim firstBoxList = TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(i).Split(",")
            Dim secondBoxList = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(3).Split(" ")
            intersectionList.Add(String.Join(",", secondBoxList.Intersect(firstBoxList)))
        Next
        TxtMReadOnly.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, intersectionList)
        TxtNumberListCount.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtMReadOnly.Text.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).Count()
        While ListBoxRemize3.Items.Count > 0
            ListBoxRemize3.Items.RemoveAt(ListBoxRemize3.Items.Count - 1)
        End While
        For i As Integer = 0 To TxtMReadOnly.Lines.Count - 1
            ListBoxRemize3.Items.Add(TxtMReadOnly.Lines(i))
        Next
        TxtMReadOnly.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the things which change in each version:

```
Dim secondBoxList = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(1).Split(" ")
Dim secondBoxList = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(2).Split(" ")
Dim secondBoxList = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(3).Split(" ")
```

```
ListBoxRemize1
ListBoxRemize2
ListBoxRemize3
```

So, you can use an array of references to the `ListBoxRemize`s, and a For loop to generate indexes:

```
Option Infer On
'..............

Dim ListBoxRemizes = {ListBoxRemize1, ListBoxRemize2, ListBoxRemize3}

For j = 0 To ListBoxRemizes.Length - 1
    Dim intersectionList As New List(Of String)()

    For i As Integer = 1 To TxtCheckDraws.Text
        Dim firstBoxList = TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(i).Split(",")
        Dim secondBoxList = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(j + 1).Split(" ")
        intersectionList.Add(String.Join(",", secondBoxList.Intersect(firstBoxList)))
    Next

    TxtMReadOnly.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, intersectionList)
    TxtNumberListCount.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtMReadOnly.Text.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).Count()

    ListBoxRemizes(j).Items.Clear()

    For i As Integer = 0 To TxtMReadOnly.Lines.Count - 1
        ListBoxRemizes(j).Items.Add(TxtMReadOnly.Lines(i))
    Next

    TxtMReadOnly.Clear()

Next
```

I used `Clear()` instead of what appeared to be code doing that a long way. Also, it looks like you could use `AddRange` instead of the loop to add those lines, somewhat like: `ListBoxRemizes(j).Items.AddRange(TxtMReadOnly.Lines)`.